# Having an issues using a hashtag target with Firefox browser

Tags: html, css, firefox

Having an issue with using a # target tag on a link when using Firefox. When the link is clicked the target on the desired page is a bit random. Sometimes it works just fine, sometimes it's off by quite a distance (i.e. the wrong part of the page). I have checked out the link on several other browsers (Safari, Google Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi, Edge and Brave) and it works just fine on all of them. Hoping some of you fine folk know what's going on and can give this numpty some advice, thanks in advance.

Link:

```
<div class="date">
  <p>
    <a href="../HTML/blog.html#jan19">January 5<sup>th</sup> 2019</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Target:

```
<div id="jan19">
  <hr><br>
  <h2>January 2019</h2>
  <hr><br>
</div>
```

For further info, this may be a VS Code / Live Server issue. The website is not yet live. I've just had another issue with a page not loading correctly when a link is used. However, if I open the page directly with Live Server everything is fine.

Link is the date (in green)
[image]

This is what should happen:
[image]

This is what happens and it's random (the date visible does not have an id tag):
[image]

Comment: It's better if you post an image of the problem, for example. When does the issue happen? Can you explain better the "sometimes it's off by quite a distance" stuff?

Comment: Thanks RHShanks - pictures added.